# Cross-match tables in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have table1 and table2. In both tables 1 field is comon.
Example:
table1 'name' field values are same as table2 'studentname' field values.

Now I want to be able to get the data by cross matching in a SELECT query.

**table1**

```
name  |  subject  | 
------+-----------+
Kyle  |  Science  |
John  |  Science  | 
Peter |  Maths    |
```

**table2**

```
score  |  studentname
-------+-------------
78     | John
89     | Kyle
83     | Peter
```

This is what I have done so far. No luck.

```
    foreach ($my_con->query("SELECT subject, examDate, table1.name, score, studentname FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.studentname SORT BY table2.score DESC") as $result){
            $gtname = $result['name'];
            $gtsubject = $result['subject'];
            $gtScore = $result['score'];
            $gtTIme = $result['date'];
```

}
        };

I expect echo to be like this:

```
Kyle   Science  89
JOHN   Science  78
```

Comment: use primary and foreign key reference

Comment: Keys aren't necessary here. What do you mean by "No luck."? Have you run the query against the database by itself? Are you getting any errors? You end the quote early (after tables2.studentname) which may be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I have. nothing seems to happen. The Everything works without the cross-matching. But I want to be able to cross-match data.

Comment: the query works when you run it on the database? If so, there is an issue somewhere else. Check your server error logs.

Comment: I've edited my post. That's my full code now. The query cross-match and calls only data less than 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

The closing quote placement in your query is probably causing the error. Change this -

```
foreach ($my_con->query("SELECT subject, table1.name, score, studentname FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.studentname" SORT BY table2.score DESC) as $result){
```

to this -

```
foreach ($my_con->query("SELECT subject, table1.name, score, studentname FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.studentname SORT BY table2.score DESC") as $result){
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `"` in wrong place in your query. Should be:

```
$my_con->query("SELECT subject, table1.name, score, studentname FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.studentname SORT BY table2.score DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it would help to know whether you are receiving a syntax error, SQL error, etc. to provide the most accurate guidance.

I didn't scrutinize syntax, but, assuming that you are using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) and you created the database connection object properly, you need to fetch the results as an associative list before dereferencing the array contents:

```
$response = $my_con->query("SELECT subject, name, score from table1, table2 where name=studentname order by score DESC");

foreach ($response->fetch_assoc() as $result) {
    $gtname = $result['name'];
    $gtsubject = $result['subject'];
    $gtScore = $result['score'];
    echo ($gtname.$gtsubject.$gtScore);
}
```

Comment: I use PDO... Looks like you've missed a chunk of my code.

Comment: Gotcha.  I see that the return result from the PDO query is traversable, so there shouldn't be an issue with the foreach.  Can you embellish your question with the kind of error you're receiving?

Comment: Strange.  My recommendation is to store the query results in an intermediate object ($results), print out count($results) -- to verify how many records were returned and therefore how many iterations of the for loop there will be -- and then execute "foreach ($results as $result) { ... }".

Answer (score 0):

`SORT` is no MySql keyword. You might want to use `ORDER`.
Try to debug your query with the database. If your query won't work, the php code is only a distraction.